# Hiding SkyDrive link from My Sites

Tags: css, mysites

I'm trying to hide only the SkyDrive link from the blue menu bar on My Sites. I thought this would be fairly simple, so I opened the master page (mysite15.master) in designer and added a reference to my stylesheet (mysites.css) which includes the style to remove it:

```
a.ms-core-suiteLink-a[id$="ShellDocuments"]{
    display:none;
}
```

This works perfectly when **newsfeed** is selected but if a user clicks on **sites**, SkyDrive would be visible again. I opened /mysites/personal in designer to find a mysite15.master that did not contain the reference to my stylesheet, so I added it. But this only worked for my profile. Other user's are still seeing SkyDrive when **sites** is selected.

It seems strange that every user's **sites** page would have it's own master page. Is there somewhere (I would assume mysites15.master) where I can remove the SkyDrive link?

Answer (score 2):

On premises? If so, you could deploy a delegate control with ControlID of "SuiteLinksDelegate"

Comment: Yes. Definitely an option for us. I thought it would be easier to hide the SkyDrive link since our delegate control would essentially be an identical copy minus the SkyDrive link. Is it possible to edit the current control instead of deploying a delegate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the master page at the top level, i'd normally use the v4.master and apply the changes to that file. All the other master pages inherit from the top level master.

Comment: I opened /mysites in designer with the system account (my account could not see master pages) but editing v4.master doesn't seem to do anything. I end up with the same result.

Comment: Why are you working in the /mysites folder, goto the top level.

Comment: I was using [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-your-my-site-master-page-HA102752026.aspx#_Toc305581260) article as a reference which suggested using /mysites/masterpages for editing or changing my sites master page.